# Avoid duplicates when eager loading from hibernate with shared objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, orm

I am working on a java command line application that should keep all objects on the heap (only a few hundred). The main reason I need persistence is that I want to be able to stop the (slow-running) process at some point in time and reload the objects from a mysql database (through Hibernate). I have two class trees in which at some level objects have a reference to a shared object, looking like the following:

```
A (abstract)
 B "b1"
  \
   -> SharedClass "shared1"
  /
 Y "y1"
X (abstract)
```

Persisting works like a charm, but when I reload the objects, I get the shared object "shared1" each time as a new object back from my loading helper method. In my case, there seem to be two queries necessary, one for loading all objects for class "B", and one for loading all objects for class "Y". Thanks to the eager loading, the object "shared1" gets instantiated as a new object automagically. This is great when executing the first query for "B", but when I load for "Y", shared1 gets loaded again and gets a new object handle.

Relatively new to Java/ORM/hibernate, I naively assumed that hibernate will through some magic know which objects are already loaded, but obviously it doesn't, and if I think about it, this behavior makes some sense. As you can see below, I start two queries at initialization. I want to keep all my objects in a Collection (in a thing I call a "Store") which is initialized at reloading, and I think I need to do this starting from the root of each tree. I would like to avoid writing HQL, and an activated second-level ehcache didn't help to resolve this issue.

I'm stuck and I think I'm doing something conceptually wrong. Maybe my whole idea of persisting and loading is broken? What's the usual way to reload objects with shared references in a similar class tree in a consistent way? Is there some design pattern that can be used for such a situation?

The abstract class A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atree")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ATREE_A")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
abstract class A {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
[...]
```

Class B, which holds the ref to SharedClass

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ATREE_B")
public class B extends A {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sharedclass_fk")
    private SharedClass refFromB;
```

And the SharedClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sharedclass")
public class SharedClass {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
```

The abstract class X looks pretty much the same as A, so I think this should be enough information:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "XTREE_Y")
public class Y extends X {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sharedclass_fk")
    private SharedClass refFromY;
```

This is my initialization example code (BStore and YStore merely keep a collection of all objects):

```
    // load all B
    List<A> allA = HibernatePersistencyBottleneck.getInstance().loadAll(A.class);
    List<B> allB = new ArrayList<>();
    for (A a : allA) {
        if (a instanceof B) {
            B b = (B) a;
            allB.add(b);
        }
    }
    BStore.initializeData(allB);

    // load all Y
    List<X> allX = HibernatePersistencyBottleneck.getInstance().loadAll(X.class);
    List<Y> allY = new ArrayList<>();
    for (X x : allX) {
        if (x instanceof Y) {
            Y y = (Y) x;
            allY.add(y);
        }
    }
```

This is my loading code (some helper stuff omitted):

```
public synchronized <E> List<E> loadAll(Class<E> o) {
    if (isPersistenceEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Going to loadAll of class: " + o.getName());
        Session session = HibernateFactory.getSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<E> retList = session.createCriteria(o).list();
        HibernateFactory.finishSession();
        return retList;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And just a simple restart (in the background, the initializer code is called)

```
public class Restart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (B b : BStore.getAll()) {
            System.out.println("Handle of shared object '" + b.getRefFromB().getName() + "' through B: "
                    + b.getRefFromB().hashCode());
        }

        for (Y y : YStore.getAll()) {
            System.out.println("Handle of shared object '" + y.getRefFromY().getName() + "' through Y: "
                    + y.getRefFromY().hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Handle of shared object 'shared1' through B: 1574160590
Handle of shared object 'shared1' through Y: 1946468420
```

I hope that's enough information, considering this is my first post here... :)

Comment: @NeilStockton, I only have javax.persistence imports, what makes you say that this has nothing to do with JPA?

Comment: Session, HibernateFactory etc are not the JPA **API**. That is Hibernate API. Use of the JPA API implies that anyone who uses/knows the JPA API can possibly help, whereas you're not using that, hence the question is for people specific to Hibernate.

Comment: I see what you mean. But my question is more about the general way of reloading and preventing duplicate objects from persistence. Which in my case happens to be Hibernate - but the problem would probably be the same with any other implementation. And in that case, the JPA annotations are IMHO the relevant part, such as FetchType.EAGER.